# How to change WCF project Platform Target to x86?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions, platform

I wrote a project that uses third party project and I can only run it if the "Platform target" under "Build" under "Project Properties" is set to "X86" and NOT "Any CPU" in My project.

However when I'm trying to use this third party project with My WCF project, the "Platform Target" feature does not appear under the WCF Project properties and therefore it fails to run.

Does anyone know how to set the "Platform Target" of a WCF project or how can I make the third party project run on "Any CPU"

Thanks !

**Update:**
Hi,
First of all thanks
Second, I've tried what Steve suggested however the project does not offer me x86 nor create new one(like the other projects) nor change the Configuration from debug to release.

Moreover, I meant for "Platform Target" and **NOT** "Platform".
As you can see in the following screen shot **I need to change the Green Circle**. The configuration manager changes the Red Circle.
The scrren shot for Project Properties is from another project that i was able to change its "Target Properties"
Thanks !
[image]