# Changing WCF project platform to x86 return unexpected results

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

Hi I wrote WCF service that uses entity framework code first entities as data contracts for example I have Step entity:

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class Step
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Order { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string ExpectedResult { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool ContinueOnFail { get; set; }

    #region Navigation Properties
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

I have in my service function that return **IEnumrable**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IStepsService
{    
    IEnumerable<Step> GetSteps();
}
```

the target platform of my service is **Any CPU**
now I need to change my target platform to **x86**
and here is the tricky part: no error is thrown but my service now always return an empty list!
someone knows why this is happening?

I read this question: [How to change WCF project Platform Target to x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11226691/how-to-change-wcf-project-platform-target-to-x86)
but it is not answering my question.
I will be glad if you help me because the project have to be x86!
thank you.

I am adding my implementataion
in the server the implementation looks like this:

```
try
{
   steps=(from step in db.Steps
               select step).ToArray();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Tracer.Write(Tracer.TraceLevel.ERROR, "Error in getting steps from database", e);
   return null;
}

return steps;
```

and in the client it just use this... by the way I don't know if it is important but the client is ASP.NET MVC 4 that adding the service reference to this service... and the db class is class that inherit from  entity framework DbContext class...

Comment: Did you debug it? Without seeing any code, it's unlikely anyone will pull a solution out of a hat here.

Comment: yes I debug it when it x86 I see that in the server there is an IEnumerable that not empty and in the client side I get empty IEnumrable it seems like it cant deserialize the result... and also no exception is thrown!

Comment: Does it also return an empty list with the WCF Test Client?

Comment: Can you provide a repro based on your service impl?

Comment: Have you tried to return `List<Step>` ?

Comment: yes I tried List<Step> it is not matter because in the service reference it is array.

Answer (score 1):

Use a tcp packet capture software to capture the message from service to client. If no steps are in the message, then it's server-side issue. If there are steps returned, then it's client-side deserialization issue.

Comment: I did it it is a client side de-serialization issue of the ASP.NET MVC I can't figure why...